# How would I interpret this PACF and ACF graph?

Tags: time-series, arima, autocorrelation, partial-correlation

[image: ACF graph]

[image: PACF graph]

I was thinking, from the ACF it looks like a nonstationary process. Or is it an AR process? From the PACF, does that mean it is AR(1)? There are 2 significant spikes in the PACF. I'm confused.

Comment: what sort of data is it on?

Comment: it is a time series data of a commodity price (natural log of real prices not nominal). Its sugar

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should have integer values on the `x-axis`...

The ACF suggests there is `long memory` present in the data set. You might try to estimate it - have a look at the [options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-range_dependence).

In terms of PACF, it suggests what is the order of autocorrelation in the series, but in this case the spike is at 10th and personally, I would assume that `AR(1)` with $x_{t-10}$ won't really explain much. But it depends what sort of data is it on, maybe it makes sense...

Comment: Generally noninteger values on the $x$-axis are not a problem. This could be monthly data with a period of 12, then a `1` on the axis stands for 1 year. Also, why long memory? Looks like ACF has an exponential (rather than linear) decay, hence short memory.

Comment: Is there evidence of the time series being Non-stationary, judging from the acf?

Comment: @user7035336 Yes, actually, there could be a unit root (and then long memory, indeed).

Comment: @user7035336 if you are doing it on log prices, then I bet you made a mistake - I was gonna say you modelled the ACF on prices as they are always non-stationary `~` unit root and similar shape :)  You want to take natural logarithm and then difference those to get logarithmic differences - thats' what finance works with. Try that and have a look at the ACF and PACF again.